# match python regex url exactly

Tags: python, regex

I have the following:

```
rule = "http://www.abc.com/"
test = "http://www.abc.com/test"
print(str(re.compile(rule).match(test)))
```

I want this to output None but instead it returns a match. How can I change the rule variable so the regex returns None?

Comment: You need to escape your periods in the rule by the way. If you don't, something like `"http://www3abc3com/"` might match. At least I think so... I could be wrong though. But try testing it out.

Comment: Wrap the regex with `^` and `$` and escape the dots

Comment: Tried making rule = "^http://www\.abc\.com/$" but still no luck. What am I missing? edit: nevermind, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` character matches the beginning of the string, and `$` matches the end of the string. So you'd want:

```
rule = "^http://www\.abc\.com/$"
test = "http://www.abc.com/test"
print(str(re.compile(rule).match(test)))
```

Note that `.` means "match any character" so if you want to match an actual `.` you need the `\` before it.

Comment: Just curious, is the ^ necessary since python's match automatically starts at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you're using match, it's not necessary. If you're using search instead of match however, it it necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you need regexp here if you wish to compare full strings. Please correct me if I misunderstand you. :)

May be this code will be uesful:

```
rule = "http://www.abc.com/"
test = "http://www.abc.com/test"
print(rule == test)
```

Returns `False` if strings are different, `True` otherwise.

Comment: Of course I can just check for equality, but unfortunately I do need regexp in this current situation :)